# Buffer Name Surrounded by Asterisks (*)

Tags: buffers, elisp-conventions

For example, `*scratch*`, `*Messages*`.

Is this some kind of convention?  
If so, what does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s just a convention. The purpose of this convention is to make it easy to distinguish buffers which content was created or generated by eLisp from buffers representing content of files.

Comment: Or buffers that are not associated with files such as `*scratch*`. There are also buffer names that start with space. Those are normally not shown in buffer lists.

Comment: It would be better if you could provide the corresponding references to the manual.

Comment: In principle I agree with you, but in practice there might not be anything to refer to. A quick glance through the Emacs manual finds a paragrah in chapter 19.1 that recommends not creating buffers whose name starts with a space, but nothing about the asterisks. Although plenty of chapters mention commands that open “a buffer named \*…\*”; anyone who reads a few of those will get the idea pretty quickly.

Comment: Same with the Emacs Lisp manual. “It seems you shall have to continue your search; they can hide well enough to escape my mere glance.”

Comment: They are not necessarily generated from buffers that are visiting files (e.g. `*scratch*` and `*Messages*` are not). They are "special" buffers of any kind: session buffers for inferior command processors are commonly named like this, log buffers  and command output buffers are too, help and Info buffers, package listings, buffer listings, tramp work buffers etc, etc. Basically, any time that some package needs a buffer for a scratch pad/logging/comand output, it is likely to use this convention.

Comment: [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Buffer) also states "By convention, buffers whose names start with an asterisk (\*) are not associated with files. ", but I couldn't find *official blessing* for that statement in the manuals / mailing lists.

Comment: @NickD, I think you might have misparsed my statement :)

Comment: Yeah, I did :-) Sorry about that: may I suggest you invert the order?

Comment: I could add parentheses…